# C# discord bot unknown opcode 8 when attempting to play youtube audio through voice channel

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am working on a C# discord.net 1.0.0 discord bot currently, and i was atempting to add a command that allows the bot to play youtube audio through the voice chat, however, when the bot joins the voice chat and tries to play the audio, my console just returns :

```
16:57:42 Audio #1    Connecting
16:57:42 Audio #1    Unknown OpCode (8)
16:57:42 Audio #1    Connected
```

if someone tells me to goto the discord api, i already went there, and they were not much help for me personaly
however, my code is:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord;
using Discordbot;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Discord.Audio;
using System;

public class AudioModule : ModuleBase<ICommandContext>
{
private readonly AudioService _service;
public static IAudioClient client;
private Process CreateStream(string url)
{
    Process currentsong = new Process();
    try
    {
        currentsong.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "youtube-dl.exe",
            Arguments = $"-o - {url} | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 
 48000 pipe:1",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    currentsong.Start();
    return currentsong;
    } 
 [Command("play", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
 public async Task play(string url)
 {
    IVoiceChannel channel = (Context.User as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel;
    IAudioClient client = await channel.ConnectAsync();

    var output = CreateStream(url).StandardOutput.BaseStream;
    var stream = client.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Music, 128 * 1024);
    await output.CopyToAsync(stream);
    await stream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

   }
```

Comment: You work with a shell here (you use pipes, etc.)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpCode 8 is a Gateway [Request Guild Members](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-request-guild-members) request. The fact an Unkown OpCode 8 occurs should not hinder your bot in playing music in anyway, and can be safely ignored.

You might want to check your process is working correctly instead

```
  currentsong.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "youtube-dl.exe",
        Arguments = $"-o - {url} | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
```